How display image outside grid container to fill all available space to the right dynamically
I have a question regarding the <img> element, how can I display it - so it goes outside the grid container and fills dynamically the rest of the space to right (stretches and fills space available space on the right on all screens).
I am using Tailwind CSS, so up to xl breakpoint everything seems alright, but once screen size is bigger than 1280px image is being wrapped in container and I can't figure out how can I display the image - to fill all available space on right.
So, basically I want the image to go out from grid-column and grid itself and dynamically stretches (fill) the remaining space on the right, when screen size is bigger than 1280px.
I assume it's possible with negative "margin-right" and possibly with css "calc" function. Unfortunately, I can't really figure out how and what I should calculate.
Here is visual reference from Tailwind Play, I want this image on the right to stretch in full width - fill up the all available space to the right.
Link for visual reference - https://play.tailwindcss.com/88w9ri2eCy?layout=preview
My HTML looks like this:
<!-- Footer grid start -->
<div class="container grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3">
  <!-- Footer image -->
  <div class="col-span-1 md:col-span-2 lg:order-3 lg:col-span-1">
    <div class="footer-img-container mx-[-16px] sm:mx-[-32px] xl:ml-0">
      <img
        class="h-[130px] w-full object-cover md:h-[200px] lg:h-[320px]"
        src="https://www.simplilearn.com/ice9/free_resources_article_thumb/what_is_image_Processing.jpg"
      />
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Footer Navigation links -->
  <div class="col-span-1 pb-6 pt-12 md:pb-12 lg:order-1 lg:col-span-1">
    <nav class="footer-nav flex flex-col">
      <a data-i18n="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      <a data-i18n="nav-link-1" href="all-services.html">Link</a>
      <a data-i18n="nav-link-2" href="about.html">Link</a>
      <a data-i18n="nav-link-3" href="#">Link</a>
      <a data-i18n="nav-link-4" href="#">Link</a>
    </nav>
    <!-- Contact button -->
    <a
      data-i18n="quote-button"
      class="button-primary mt-6 block self-start"
      href=""
    >
    </a>
  </div>

  <!-- Contact info details -->
  <div class="col-span-1 pb-12 md:pt-12 lg:order-2 lg:col-span-1">
    <div class="flex flex-col">
      <div class="span pb-3">Contact info text</div>
      <p><a href="#">Phone</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">E-pasts: info@test.com</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">Address</a></p>
    </div>
    <!-- Social icons footer -->
    <div class="inline-flex pt-8">
      <!-- Instagram -->
      <a href="#" class="self-center pr-4">
        <svg width="42" height="42">
          <use xlink:href="#instagram"></use>
        </svg>
      </a>
      <!-- Facebook -->
      <a href="#" class="self-center pr-4">
        <svg width="42" height="42">
          <use xlink:href="#facebook"></use>
        </svg>
      </a>
      <!-- Whatsapp -->
      <a href="#" class="self-center">
        <svg width="42" height="42">
          <use xlink:href="#whatsapp"></use>
        </svg>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Copyrights footer -->
<div class="w-dvw bg-secondary py-5">
  <div class="container xl:flex xl:justify-between">
    <div class="flex flex-col space-y-1 lg:flex-row lg:space-y-0 xl:order-2">
      <a class="lg:pr-6" href="#">Link</a>
      <a class="lg:pr-6" href="#">Link</a>
      <a href="#">Link</a>
    </div>
    <p class="mt-3 inline-block text-[12px] md:text-[16px] xl:order-1 xl:mt-0">
      Copyrights texts
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Footer grid end -->

CSS code for container:
.container {
  max-width: 1280px;
  width: 100%;
  @apply relative mx-auto px-4;
  @screen sm {
    @apply px-8;
  }
}

I tried:
margin-right: -100%, 

It kind of works, but I am sure there is better way to do it.

The calculation you'd want somewhere is:
x = (100cqw - 1280px) ÷ 2
  =   50cqw - 640px

These values come from:
┏━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━┓
┃  │    .container    │  ┃
┃  │                  │  ┃
┃  ←––––– 1280px –––––→  ┃
←–––––––– 100cqw ––––––––→

You can use this calculation in several ways in your code. As example, on the <img> element itself:


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<style type="text/tailwindcss">
.container {
  max-width: 1280px;
  width: 100%;
  @apply relative mx-auto px-4;
  @apply sm:px-8;
}
</style>

<!-- Footer grid start -->
<div class="container grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3">
  <!-- Footer image -->
  <div class="col-span-1 md:col-span-2 lg:order-3 lg:col-span-1">
    <div class="footer-img-container mx-[-16px] sm:mx-[-32px] xl:ml-0">
      <img
        class="h-[130px] w-full max-w-none object-cover md:h-[200px] lg:h-[320px] lg:w-[calc(100%+50cqw-640px)]"
        src="https://www.simplilearn.com/ice9/free_resources_article_thumb/what_is_image_Processing.jpg"
      />
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Footer Navigation links -->
  <div class="col-span-1 pb-6 pt-12 md:pb-12 lg:order-1 lg:col-span-1">
    <nav class="footer-nav flex flex-col">
      <a data-i18n="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      <a data-i18n="nav-link-1" href="all-services.html">Link</a>
      <a data-i18n="nav-link-2" href="about.html">Link</a>
      <a data-i18n="nav-link-3" href="#">Link</a>
      <a data-i18n="nav-link-4" href="#">Link</a>
    </nav>
    <!-- Contact button -->
    <a
      data-i18n="quote-button"
      class="button-primary mt-6 block self-start"
      href=""
    >
    </a>
  </div>

  <!-- Contact info details -->
  <div class="col-span-1 pb-12 md:pt-12 lg:order-2 lg:col-span-1">
    <div class="flex flex-col">
      <div class="span pb-3">Contact info text</div>
      <p><a href="#">Phone</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">E-pasts: info@test.com</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">Address</a></p>
    </div>
    <!-- Social icons footer -->
    <div class="inline-flex pt-8">
      <!-- Instagram -->
      <a href="#" class="self-center pr-4">
        <svg width="42" height="42">
          <use xlink:href="#instagram"></use>
        </svg>
      </a>
      <!-- Facebook -->
      <a href="#" class="self-center pr-4">
        <svg width="42" height="42">
          <use xlink:href="#facebook"></use>
        </svg>
      </a>
      <!-- Whatsapp -->
      <a href="#" class="self-center">
        <svg width="42" height="42">
          <use xlink:href="#whatsapp"></use>
        </svg>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Copyrights footer -->
<div class="w-dvw bg-secondary py-5">
  <div class="container xl:flex xl:justify-between">
    <div class="flex flex-col space-y-1 lg:flex-row lg:space-y-0 xl:order-2">
      <a class="lg:pr-6" href="#">Link</a>
      <a class="lg:pr-6" href="#">Link</a>
      <a href="#">Link</a>
    </div>
    <p class="mt-3 inline-block text-[12px] md:text-[16px] xl:order-1 xl:mt-0">
      Copyrights texts
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Footer grid end -->



Or we can have it on the <img> element's parent element:


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<style type="text/tailwindcss">
.container {
  max-width: 1280px;
  width: 100%;
  @apply relative mx-auto px-4;
  @apply sm:px-8;
}
</style>

<!-- Footer grid start -->
<div class="container grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3">
  <!-- Footer image -->
  <div class="col-span-1 md:col-span-2 lg:order-3 lg:col-span-1">
    <div class="footer-img-container mx-[-16px] sm:mx-[-32px] xl:ml-0 lg:mr-[calc(640px-50cqw-theme(spacing.8))]">
      <img
        class="h-[130px] w-full object-cover md:h-[200px] lg:h-[320px]"
        src="https://www.simplilearn.com/ice9/free_resources_article_thumb/what_is_image_Processing.jpg"
      />
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Footer Navigation links -->
  <div class="col-span-1 pb-6 pt-12 md:pb-12 lg:order-1 lg:col-span-1">
    <nav class="footer-nav flex flex-col">
      <a data-i18n="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      <a data-i18n="nav-link-1" href="all-services.html">Link</a>
      <a data-i18n="nav-link-2" href="about.html">Link</a>
      <a data-i18n="nav-link-3" href="#">Link</a>
      <a data-i18n="nav-link-4" href="#">Link</a>
    </nav>
    <!-- Contact button -->
    <a
      data-i18n="quote-button"
      class="button-primary mt-6 block self-start"
      href=""
    >
    </a>
  </div>

  <!-- Contact info details -->
  <div class="col-span-1 pb-12 md:pt-12 lg:order-2 lg:col-span-1">
    <div class="flex flex-col">
      <div class="span pb-3">Contact info text</div>
      <p><a href="#">Phone</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">E-pasts: info@test.com</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">Address</a></p>
    </div>
    <!-- Social icons footer -->
    <div class="inline-flex pt-8">
      <!-- Instagram -->
      <a href="#" class="self-center pr-4">
        <svg width="42" height="42">
          <use xlink:href="#instagram"></use>
        </svg>
      </a>
      <!-- Facebook -->
      <a href="#" class="self-center pr-4">
        <svg width="42" height="42">
          <use xlink:href="#facebook"></use>
        </svg>
      </a>
      <!-- Whatsapp -->
      <a href="#" class="self-center">
        <svg width="42" height="42">
          <use xlink:href="#whatsapp"></use>
        </svg>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Copyrights footer -->
<div class="w-dvw bg-secondary py-5">
  <div class="container xl:flex xl:justify-between">
    <div class="flex flex-col space-y-1 lg:flex-row lg:space-y-0 xl:order-2">
      <a class="lg:pr-6" href="#">Link</a>
      <a class="lg:pr-6" href="#">Link</a>
      <a href="#">Link</a>
    </div>
    <p class="mt-3 inline-block text-[12px] md:text-[16px] xl:order-1 xl:mt-0">
      Copyrights texts
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Footer grid end -->



